# Sort temp table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a temp table in which I have a `SortOrder` column. Initially while inserting data in it I sort the data while inserting

```
INSERT INTO #MainCalcTemp
    SELECT  
        ItemId, ItemDesc, Quantity, Rate, Frequency,
        Annual, BasedOn, ProductCode, CalculationID, SortOrder 
    FROM 
        OneTimeFeesDocTemplate
    ORDER BY 
        SortOrder ASC
```

Now I add some data dynamically to it by using below SQL

```
INSERT INTO #MainCalcTemp
    SELECT 
        ItemID, ItemDesc, quantity, Rate, '', Annual, '', 'PHR', '', 2
    FROM
        #PackageInfoPHR 
    WHERE
        ItemID IN ('1PHR', '2PHR', '3PHR', '4PHR', '5PHR', '6PHR', '7PHR', '8PHR', '9PHR', '10PHR')
```

I added the items with the `SortOrder = 2`. I need to sort the `#MainCalcTemp` table again while inside the stored procedure to output the data in a sorted way since the additional items I am adding manually are coming out at the top.

Can someone please tell me how to sort a temp table inside a stored procedure on demand so the new items that I add show up as number 2 and not on the top and I can add more items to it at desired position and sort it again.

Thanks

Comment: You can use the normal Order By as you use in User tables

Comment: In a relational database, you cannot *sort* a table per se - the only way to get a sorted result set is to use an explicit `ORDER BY` when you retrieve the data

Comment: In addition to what marc_s is telling, you can't insert into a table in a particular order; the `ORDER BY` clause in the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... ORDER BY` statement is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Having known [that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described):

> The only time the data rows in a table are stored in sorted order is
>   when the table contains a clustered index. When a table has a
>   clustered index, the table is called a clustered table. If a table has
>   no clustered index, its data rows are stored in an unordered structure
>   called a heap.

means if we want to stored the rows in particular format, we need to create a clustered table.

We need some value, that will be always greater then the value of the last row inserted in the table and looking in your columns it seems there is not such value.

What we can do is to add a `PRIMARY KEY` (by default it is marked as clustered) to your table and make the column `IDENTITY`:

```
CREATE TABLE #MainCalcTemp
(
   [RowID] INT IDENTITY(100,1)
   ,...
);
```

Now, the rows will be inserted following your define order each time.

Do you need to do that? It will be better to have more meaningful `PRIMARY KEY` which stored data in such format that your most common executed query are optimized. The topic is long, [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72399/) you can find the basics.

Note, that:

1. You can always order the rows when data is read
2. A table in T-SQL is supposed to represent a relation; a relation is a set, and a set has no order to its elements.

Comment: But there is still no guarantee that records will be returned in the order of the clustered index.. unless you add an `order by` to the select